# Error when running packer build both from Azure CLI and Portal command prompt

Tags: azure, azure-devops, packer

*azure-arm: error fetching subscriptionID from VM metadata service for Managed Identity authentication: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value*
**The above error is gotten when running packer build from Azure CLI locally**

*Build 'azure-arm' errored after 3 milliseconds 526 microseconds: error fetching subscriptionID from VM metadata service for Managed Identity authentication: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value*
**The above error is gotten when running packer build from Azure Cloud shell**

I already have the resource group created in Azure and still get the error. below is the sample code:

```
{
"variables": {
  "client_id": "",
  "client_secret": "",
  "subscription_id": ""
},
"builders": [{
  "type": "azure-arm",

  "client_id": "{{user `client_id`}}",
  "client_secret": "{{user `client_secret`}}",
  "subscription_id": "{{user `subscription_id`}}",

  "os_type": "Linux",
  "image_publisher": "Canonical",
  "image_offer": "UbuntuServer",
  "image_sku": "18.04-LTS",

  "managed_image_resource_group_name": "packer-rg",
  "managed_image_name": "myPackerImage",

  "location": "East US",
  "vm_size": "Standard_A2"
}],
"provisioners": [{
  "inline": [
      "apt-get update",
      "apt-get upgrade -y"
  ],
  "inline_shebang": "/bin/sh -x",
  "type": "shell",
  "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .Path }}'"
}]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to add the subscription ID and make sure that the Resource group is located in the right region